# Handle overlapping a window by the taskbar in WinAPI

Tags: winapi, z-order, taskbar

I have a window which should pop up on top of any other windows (including the taskbar), stay on top while in focus, and become hidden completely when focus is lost.

To achieve this, I'm handling `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` with `wParam` being equal to `FALSE`. Nevertheless, sometimes the window falls in behind the taskbar, and since it's small, it's wholly overlapped by it. So, no way to reactivate it and take focus back to hide.

So, I'm looking for a way to handle that event, when the window Z-order changed relative to the taskbar one.

Regards,

**UPDATE**

I'm pointing to the fact, that this is not that type of questions, you know, how to stay on top forever. In fact, otherwise. It's about how to hide the window as soon as possible.

**UPDATE 2**

I have tried WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, but it never received, when I click on the taskbar and overlap my window.

Comment: I have another window, not your window, which should be on top of any other window. What shall we do about this unfortunate coincidence?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In this case my window should be hidden as well, because it has lost focus. I guess, `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` will be sent and my window will be closed. But when the taskbar overlaps the window, `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` sometimes is not received, I don't know why. This is why the tasbar seems to be a special case.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Also, if you make your window special in the same way as the taskbar, I have no other way to close my window but comparing your Z-order and mine. Actually, I've found WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING + GetNextWindow() technique. Maybe that will be the solution.

Comment: No, I'm making my window special in the exact same way as you are doing. It's a bit of a shame, but we can't both be special. Oh well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In the same way? You too close your window when it's become overlapped? So what? We both CAN be special, if being special means closing on losing focus. I see now you're totally missing the point.

Comment: Are you just asking how to make a window top-most? `SetWindowPos(...HWND_TOPMOST...);`

Comment: Um... how exactly does the window "fall in" behind the taskbar? And are you trying to make a temporary pop up window that responds to some global hot key or notification icocn event or something?